# VB.net InternetExplorer HtmlDocument

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help me? I am new to VB.net and try to write a very simple code to manipulate a website. However, i keep getting

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Defer All.exe .... Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'mshtml.HTMLDocument'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '....)."

```
        Dim IE As InternetExplorer
        Dim HTMLDoc As HtmlDocument
        Dim oHTML_Element As mshtml.IHTMLElement
        IE = new InternetExplorer
        IE.Navigate("http://www.mediafire.com/")
        Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        Loop
        Loop Until Not IE.Busy
        ' ERROR on the following line
        HTMLDoc = IE.Document
        ' I tried making HTMLDoc as object. It passed the above line, but failed the next line due to no GetElementsByTagName method
        For Each oHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.GetElementsByTagName("input")
          '....................
        Next
```

Comment: You have to wait for the browser to actually navigate to the page.  Until then the Document property is, probably, null - or some other kind of indeterminate.

Comment: You wanna handle the DocumentCompleted Event.

Comment: Thank you Dan-o. Sorry, i edited my post. I did wait till everything was done. It seems that the IE.Document is a com.object and cant be casted into HTMLDocument. I have no idea why it doesnt work. It works in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change...

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HtmlDocument
'                    ^---------------------------this thing to,
                                                 mshtml.IHTMLDocument
Dim oHTML_Element As mshtml.IHTMLElement
```